# JavaFX jfoenix runtime error (JFXDatePicker)

Tags: java, runtime-error, java-11, javafx-11, jfoenix

I am developing an application with JavaFX but I have an error when I try to load an fxml interface containing a JFXDatePicker. The other interfaces load without problem

Here is the error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.jfoenix.controls.behavior.JFXGenericPickerBehavior (in unnamed module @0x534cfe42) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ComboBoxBaseBehavior (in module javafx.controls) because module javafx.controls does not export com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior to unnamed module @0x534cfe42
```

I use JDK 11 With jfoenix 9.0.9

I tried to change my jdk version but without success

Comment: I use the builder of my IDE. My IDE is Eclipse 2020. No i didn't write a module-info.java

Comment: The error message you posted indicates that there is a problem regarding the accessibility of [java modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html).

Comment: Since my project is not a modular application what could cause this problem then?

Comment: Since Java 9 ___all___ java applications ___are___ modular. Why do you claim that yours is not?

Comment: Oh right, I thought that since I didn't put a module-info.java my application wasn't modular

Answer (score 1):

Run -> Edit Configuration -> Modify option -> Add VM option ->

```
--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: Not working. Still seeing the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else using SceneBuilder, I added this to app/build.gradle file:

```
    doFirst {
        jvmArgs += ['--add-opens=javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml=ALL-UNNAMED' ]
        jvmArgs += ['--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=ALL-UNNAMED' ] 
        jvmArgs += ['--add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=ALL-UNNAMED' ] 
        jvmArgs += ['--add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding=ALL-UNNAMED' ]
        jvmArgs += ['--add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=ALL-UNNAMED' ] 
        jvmArgs += ['--add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED' ]
        if (javafx.platform.classifier == 'linux') jvmArgs += '-Djdk.gtk.version=2'
    }
```